# Android Studio Messages window

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

How can I configure Android Studio/IntelliJ Idea to show more than 101 error messages when compiling?

I know there are more than 101 errors, but I am using Android Annotations and I get a lot of import errors when something is wrong. Those import errors fill up the messages window and I can't see the actual errors that need to be fixed.

Thanks!

[image: example]

Comment: why are you getting import errors ? which annotations are you using ?

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem. Maybe if you showed the import errors, then we could tell you how to fix them, so you'd have less than 101 errors and you could see them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 101 error limit is imposed by the underlying compiler , not the IDE. So to increase it, you have to change the default compiler settings.

Go To : `Preferences` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Compiler`.

There, you'll find an option of passing additional command line options to the compiler. There you can change the max errors limit.

The compiler used by Android studio is `javac` and it offers the following options :

```
-Xmaxerrs number : Set the maximum number of errors to print.

-Xmaxwarns number : Set the maximum number of warnings to print. `
```

So, you can pass :

`-Xmaxerrs 400 -Xmaxwarns 1000` to make the maximum errors reported to 400 and maximum warnings reported to 1000.

That's **one way** to do it in IDE UI and change it **globally** for all projects.

You can also set this for a **specific project** by passing these command line options to the compiler through the `gradle` file of the project. Here's the syntax for that:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "400" << " -Xmaxwarns" << "1000"
}
```

Comment: After four years, still relevant. Setting -Xmaxerrs through gradle doesn't seem to work for me, and when I try to set it as compile options in preferences and build the project, it just immediately says "build failed" with zero additional information. Could you please specify how exactly to set it there?

Answer (score 1):

In Gradle, change the `allprojects`  of your Project `build.gradle` as following:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    // Allow 400 errors.
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "400"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As everybody pointed out, maximum errors displayed is a Compiler rather than an Android Studio setting. I am using kotlin annotation processor `kapt` for incremental compilation of databinding, room and dagger. The following addition to `build.gradle` solved the problem:

```
kapt {
    javacOptions {
        // Increase the max count of errors from annotation processors.
        option("-Xmaxerrs", 500)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone, when applying the various other options suggested I kept seeing 50 errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, how to force Messages window show more than 101 errors, but maybe this would help.

At the end of Messages window you can see:
[image]

Or you can call console from icon:
[image]

Here how it looks:
[image]

I believe you can find all information there.
Also there is a possibility to export log to text file, this also might help you.

Thanks.

Comment: The console has the same number of errors...the compiler won't show more than 101...@Yashasvi's answer does the trick

Answer (score -2):

Add the Android Annotations Support JAR to your `build.gradle` -

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
```

This should get rid of the import errors.